# System.in.read() returns 3 times when I enter a single character

Tags: java

I'm studying the book Java: A Beginner's Guide, and where it explains the for loop, it uses a variation where the condition contais an user input:

```
class ForTest {   
  public static void main(String[] args)   
    throws java.io.IOException { 
 
    int i; 
 
    System.out.println("Press S to stop."); 
 
    for(i = 0; (char) System.in.read() != 'S'; i++) 
      System.out.println("Pass #" + i); 
  }   
}
```

when I executed this code, the output was different than I expected. After I typed one character and pressed enter, the program printed the "Pass #" three times, instead of one. Why is the loop running more than once?

Here is a sample of the output I've got:

```
a
Pass #0
Pass #1
Pass #2
w
Pass #3
Pass #4
Pass #5
1
Pass #6
Pass #7
Pass #8
2
Pass #9
Pass #10
Pass #11
```

Comment: You are on Windows. When you enter `a` that is one character. But when you press enter, that is two characters `\r\n`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That sounds like an answer.  If you can put it in the Answer box, people will be able to vote on it.

Comment: Should the tile also be changed? "System.in.read() returns 3 times when I enter a single character"

Comment: I agree. It's done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is passing more times than you expected because System.in will also read an enter key press as a new line character (\r\n on Windows).